# Simplifying file comparison in a shell script

Tags: shell, freebsd, opnsense

I have this shell running in OPNSense to check any new DHCP releases that don't match with the table and send an alert email. However, this code is very cpu consuming. I might try to put the changes of the given time period, and compare those.

Do you guys any have any better ideas?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# Define the location of the static DHCP release file
STATIC_DHCP_FILE="/var/dhcpd/etc/dhcpd.conf"

# Define the location of the new DHCP release file
NEW_DHCP_FILE="/var/log/dhcpd/latest.log"

# Define the subject of the email
SUBJECT="New DHCP Release Detected"

# Define the last line of the file
LAST_LINE=$(tail -n 1 "$NEW_DHCP_FILE")

# Create last line file
touch /tmp/last_match

while true; do
    # Check if the file has changed
    if ! cmp -s /tmp/last_match "$NEW_DHCP_FILE"; then # Use cmp instead of diff
        LAST_LINE=$(tail -n 1 "$NEW_DHCP_FILE")
        DHCP_MODE=$(echo "$LAST_LINE" | awk '{print $9}')
        if [ "$DHCP_MODE" == "DHCPOFFER" ]; then
            IP=$(echo "$LAST_LINE" | awk '{print $11}')
            MAC=$(echo "$LAST_LINE" | awk '{print $13}')
            ETH=$(echo "$LAST_LINE" | awk '{print $15}')
            if  ! grep -qi "$MAC" "$STATIC_DHCP_FILE"; then
        # Run the nmap command and store the output in a variable
        OUTPUT=$(nmap -sP "$IP")
        # Extract the hostname from the output using grep and cut
        HOSTNAME=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -m 1 "Nmap scan report for" | cut -d " " -f 5)
                echo "$LAST_LINE" > /tmp/last_match
                BODY=`printf "A new DHCP release has been detected for an unknown device. The details are as follows:\n\nOn $(date)\nIP Address: $IP\nMAC Address: $MAC\nHostname: $HOSTNAME\n"`
                echo -e "$BODY"
                sleep 3
                python3 /root/sendmail.py -s "$SUBJECT" -a "$BODY"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why don't just do the `diff`?

Comment: _very cpu consuming_ : Well, it's an infinite loop, and as such tends to be CPU hungry. You just give your CPU 3 seconds to rest in each iteration, and even this you do only if all three `if` are true. While you **can** simplify a lot (spawning two child processes just to calculate `DHCP_MODE` is sure a waste of cycles), you still would keep your CPU busy; it's just it would iterate more often in a given amount of time. You could have your script triggered [only if `last_match` changes](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=inotifywait&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports).

Comment: BTW, since you are on BSD, where the Kernel has no `notify` for notifying file changes, it could be that you need to [install some emulation](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/inotify-tools) of this feature first. If you want to implement your own solution, at least don't do a `cmp` on every loop iteration. Instead first check the time stamp of the file: Only if time stamp **and** size have changed between 2 iterations, do a `cmp`. In addition, do a sleep in the outermost level of your loop. It should be enough to check for a file change every second or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `awk` multiple times when only one is needed.

More importantly, don't busy-wait / poll. Just read new data when it arrives.

For example:

```
static_dhcp_file=/var/dhcpd/etc/dhcpd.conf
new_dhcp_file=/var/log/dhcpd/latest.log

subject="New DHCP Release Detected"

tail -f -n1 "$new_dhcp_file" |
while read _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ mode _ ip _ mac _ eth _; do 
    if [[ $mode = DHCP_OFFER ]] && ! grep -qi $mac "$static_dhcp_file"; then
        host=$(nmap -sP $ip | awk '/Nmap scan report for/ { print $5; exit }')
        body=$(printf "A new DHCP release has been detected for an unknown device. The details are as follows:\n\nOn $(date)\nIP Address: ${ip}\nMAC Address: ${mac}\nHostname: ${host}\n")
        echo "$body"
        sleep 3
        python3 /root/sendmail.py -s "$subject" -a "$body"
    fi
done
```

Note that your original code could theoretically miss changes. If more than one new line is added to `latest.log` during your `sleep 3`, only the final one will be noticed.